# Break a string down to ASCII numbers

Tags: c#, ascii

I'm trying to find away to take a string and store it as an array of its ASCII values as ints

ie; string 1 = hello
array 72,69, etc

Comment: Why?  A string already _is_ an array of chars.

Comment: What if the string contains characters which are not part of the ASCII character set?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: No, they are two different things. To start with: A string is immutable whereas an array of characters isn't.

Comment: @MartinStettner the string class internally maintains an array of characters.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, but nevertheless, they are different things from the language perspective. For example, the "inner" array might be shared between different `String` instances, which btw is because `String`s are immutable. If they were the 'same' thing, you woudn't need a string class ...

Comment: @MartinStettner  If yor are referring to the string pool, I would say that is something completely different. But I get your point, they are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
```

Comment: Be aware of the transformations that happen here when your input string is not pure ASCII.

Comment: The `var` kind of hides that the result is a `byte[]`

Comment: Well, the function is called `GetBytes`

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Henk's comment, a string is already an array of 16-bit integers (shorts), representing each character's Unicode code point (but see below). If your string is composed entirely of "ASCII" (code points below 128), then running the below will produce what you expect:

```
string s = "hello";
foreach (char c in s)
{
    Console.WriteLine((short)c);
}
```

> 104
>   101
>   108
>   108
>   111

Use `s.ToCharArray()` to extract that array and do with it what you will. Note that strings can contain any Unicode character, and your program needs to comprehend that (including the case where a single character needs more than one short to represent it).

Comment: How could I use this to order a set of strings alphabetically

Comment: If you need to order a collection of strings. `myList.OrderBy(s => s);`

Answer (score 0):

Do you insist on ASCII encoding (what about all other possible characters)?. If not, i.e. if you want an array of unicode characters I'd suggest using

```
myString.ToCharArray();
```

or

```
myString.ToCharArray().Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

(the latter if you need `int` values)